# Default value for add_settings_field

Tags: customization, settings-api

I'm creating a simple settings page by following [these instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages).

Since this is a custom plugin, I'd like one of my settings to start with a predefined value (that can later be changed). What is the recommended way to set a default value for a setting added with `add_settings_field`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( get_option( 'my_setting' ) === false ) // Nothing yet saved
    update_option( 'my_setting', 'default_stuff' );
```

Comment: Its worth noting that if you're doing theme development (using Wordpress's theme customization API) that get_theme_mod() has a parameter for defaults. So `get_theme_mod("secondary_header_text", "Hello world");`

Comment: Just to be clear, the difference is my snippet "pushes" a default option to the db, whereas `get_theme_mod` will return the default arg if there isn't one yet set in the db.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, where does this code go?  I have it here but it doesn't seem to populate it.

    `add_action( 'admin_init', 'myVendorPrefix_mysettings_init' );
function myVendorPrefix_mysettings_init() {
   ...
   if ( get_option( 'my_setting' ) === false ) // Nothing yet saved
    update_option( 'my_setting', 'default_stuff' );
}
`